# Is there a better way to filter NULL,false and empty strings from an array (and leave ZERO)?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I would like to filter NULL, false and empty strings from an array but not the zero values. That is my code but it doesent work at all:

```
$array = array(1,2,3, "Test", NULL, 0, '', false);
$result = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if(!empty($value) && !is_null($value) && false !== $value){
        $result[] = $value;
    }

}

print_r($result);
```

The Output should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => Test
    [5] => 0
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the array_filter function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the php built in functions array_filter() and strlen() to solve this. There is a nice reference on php.net too:

```
$array = array(1,2,3, "Test", NULL, 0, '', false);
$result = array_filter($array, 'strlen');
print_r($result);
```

For me the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => Test
    [5] => 0
)
```

That should help.